# How to compile and run multiple classes with an activemq.jar dependency?

Tags: java, eclipse, activemq-classic

My goal is to succesfully compile and run my java code, consisting of an external library (activemq) and multiple external java classes. This is an example of my folder structure:

> /code/**client**/link/to/file/**client**

This folder just contains my `Client.java`, which I want to compile and run.

> /code/**helper**/link/to/file/**helper**

This folder contains multiple `.java`-files which are imported by `client.java`.

> /jar_folder/activemq-all-5.15.13.jar

I added the jar-file to the buildpath of my project in eclipse. And I do not get any warnings or errors presented in eclipse. When I hit "run"-button, I get following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/jms/Destination
```

Eventhoug I just import following classes from the `activemq.jar`:

```
import javax.jms.Connection;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.MessageConsumer;
import javax.jms.MessageListener;
import javax.jms.MessageProducer;
import javax.jms.ObjectMessage;
import javax.jms.Queue;
import javax.jms.Session;
import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;
```

Since I did not find a solution for my problem over the past two days, I tried to compile and run my code via the console - without succes.

```
find -name "*.java" > sources.txt

javac -d bin/ -cp '/jar_folder/activemq-all-5.15.13.jar':. @sources.txt
```

It actually compiles every `.java`-file without an error, but when I try to run the client/class with:

```
java -cp '/jar_folder/activemq-all-5.15.13.jar':. Client
```

I get following error: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: /link/to/file/client/Client (wrong name: Client)`

Can somebody please help me with my problem, because I really want to test my code.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you tried using Maven to manage this? It's pretty simple and takes care of all this stuff automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should use this command to run your application:

```
java -cp '/jar_folder/activemq-all-5.15.13.jar':./bin client/link/to/file/client/Client
```